# Why can't I use libxml2.dylib?

Tags: ios, libxml2

I have drag it into the framework, and set Header Search Paths of both projects and targets to ${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2.2, I also add it to Link binary With Libraries, I import them, but it still can't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Its ${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2 or what you have ${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2 , remove .2